# dplyr mean problems (argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA)

Tags: r

```
DF <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4), A = c(1,2,10,4,8,NA,NA,2))
```

Why doesn´t this work?:

```
DF%>%mean(A,na.rm=T)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(., A, na.rm = T) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

But his does?:

```
> mean(DF$A,na.rm=T)
[1] 4.5


glimpse(DF)
Observations: 8
Variables: 2
$ id <chr> "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4"
$ A  <dbl> 1, 2, 10, 4, 8, NA, NA, 2
```

The idea later on is to mutate() a new column with mean for every id.

Best H

EDIT:

Additional question. Thanks for your answers. Now I want to calculate mean in each group - but duplicates of values are just allowed to be counted once. See example.

I want this:

```
DF<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), A=c(2,2,1,1,2,3,4,4,1,NA,2,2))
> DF
   id  A
1   1  2
2   1  2
3   1  1
4   2  1
5   2  2
6   2  3
7   3  4
8   3  4
9   3  1
10  4 NA
11  4  2
12  4  2
```

To end like this:

```
  id  A mean
1   1  2  1.5
2   1  2  1.5
3   1  1  1.5
4   2  1    2
5   2  2    2
6   2  3    2
7   3  4  2.5
8   3  4  2.5
9   3  1  2.5
10  4 NA    2
11  4  2    2
12  4  2    2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mean` expects a vector while 'A' is not getting extracted.  We can use `.$`

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
    {mean(.$A, na.rm = TRUE)}
#[1] 4.5
```

Or if we want to avoid the `{}`

```
DF %>%
   .$A %>% # \\ or use: pull(A)
   mean(na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 4.5
```

Answer (score 1):

the `mean` function takes vectors, not dataframes, as its argument, so you can't just pipe in `DF`. You have to use `summarize`:

```
DF %>%
  summarize(mean(A, na.rm = TRUE))

  mean(A, na.rm = TRUE)
1                   4.5
```

If you want a group-wise mean, you can use `group_by`:

```
DF %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(mean(A, na.rm = TRUE))

     id `mean(A, na.rm = TRUE)`
  <dbl>                   <dbl>
1     1                     1.5
2     2                     7  
3     3                     8  
4     4                     2
```

And if you want to keep every row but add on the grouped means, you replace `summarize` with `mutate`:

```
DF %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(mean(A, na.rm = TRUE))

# Groups:   id [4]
     id     A `mean(A, na.rm = TRUE)`
  <dbl> <dbl>                   <dbl>
1     1     1                     1.5
2     1     2                     1.5
3     2    10                     7  
4     2     4                     7  
5     3     8                     8  
6     3    NA                     8  
7     4    NA                     2  
8     4     2                     2
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to keep all the rows but only count distinct ones for your average, you can use use `row_number` to reset for each unique row and then weight your mean based on whether the row number is 1:

```
DF <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), 
                 A=c(2,2,1,1,2,3,4,4,1,NA,2,2))

DF %>%
  group_by(id, A) %>%
  mutate(count = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(mean = weighted.mean(A, count == 1, na.rm = TRUE))

      id     A count  mean
   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
 1     1     2     1   1.5
 2     1     2     2   1.5
 3     1     1     1   1.5
 4     2     1     1   2  
 5     2     2     1   2  
 6     2     3     1   2  
 7     3     4     1   2.5
 8     3     4     2   2.5
 9     3     1     1   2.5
10     4    NA     1   2  
11     4     2     1   2  
12     4     2     2   2
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I´v edited the question with further information